# Proof of continuity at $x=0$

Tags: analysis, continuity

Prove $f$ is continuous at $0$, when $f(x)$ is defined as

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x^3\cos(1/x) &\mbox{if $x \ne 0$,} \\ 0 &\mbox{if $x=0$.} \end{cases}$$

Using delta-epsilon proof,
$$|f(x)-f(s)| < \varepsilon \;\dots\; |x-s| < \delta$$

since $s=0, \; f(s)=0$, so we have:

$$|(x^3)\cos\frac{1}{x}| < \varepsilon \;\dots\; |x| < \delta$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: Hint: for $|x|<1$, $|x^3 \cos({1 \over x})| < |x|*|\cos({1 \over x})|$.

Comment: FYI: If you put dollar signs around your math equations they will format much better.

Answer (score 2):

Given $\epsilon >0$, we want to find $\delta>0$ such that: $$|x-0|<\delta \implies |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon.$$

Now, $$|f(x)-f(0)|=|x^3\cos(1/x)|=|x|^3\cdot|\cos(1/x)| \leq |x|^3,$$ since $|\cos(1/x)|\leq1$ for all $x \ne 0$.

Hence, this suggests we should pick $\delta=\epsilon^{1/3}$. So with this choice of $\delta$, we have: $$|x|<\delta=\epsilon^{1/3} \implies |f(x)-f(0)| \leq |x|^3<\delta^3=\epsilon.$$

Comment: That's great! I could see how it worked for cos(1/x) = 1 but wasn't sure how to do it for <1. You've made it very clear